# Android | Multiple Custom ArrayAdapter in ListItem/row of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Currently I am using Firebase database in my Android project. My problem is whether I can use multiple custom ArrayAdapter in a row and if possible how to do it?

In my image below, the orange box has several views and will be populated with info of patient from Firebase database. The green box will contain several child/children or none of the patient's medication. So the design will look like one ArrayAdapter for orange box and one ArrayAdapter for the green box.

Or is there any way beside using multiple custom ArrayAdapter?

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c55P8.png)

[My Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fisjr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add multilple item to a single item from parent Listview
Called Expandable listview
 Go Through these links

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial

Comment: Can I use several views in each item?

Comment: yes sure , u can do that easily, just go through these links, it has reason why to use it and how

Answer (score 0):

You can try recyclerview inside another recyclerview

set LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL in layoutManager

look inside following code

```
private RecyclerView rclViewOrder = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rclViewOrder);
rclViewOrder.setHasFixedSize(true);
//mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

rclViewOrder.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new ViewOrderAdapter(orderList);
rclViewOrder.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple tutorial for multi lines(rows) for custom list view:

http://publicstaticdroidmain.com/2011/12/building-a-custom-multi-line-listview-in-android/